# How to fix java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Tags: java

i'm using this code to insert in 2d array but i keep geeting exception, any ideas?

```
int rows=4, columns=4, value=0;
    int[][] arySwap = new int[rows][columns];
    for (int i=0 ; i<arySwap[rows].length ; i++){
        for (int j=0 ; j<arySwap[columns].length ; j++){
            value = value+1;
            arySwap[i][j]= value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `arySwap[rows].length` -> `arySwap[columns].length` ... so the first time the outer array represents the rows, then something magical happens and then it represents the columns? What kind of magic is that?

Answer (score 0):

You try to access the fourth value of arySwap with arySwap[column] and also the fouth value with arySwap[column]. Change your code like this:

```
  int rows=4, columns=4, value=0;
        int[][] arySwap = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int i=0 ; i<rows ; i++){
            for (int j=0 ; j<arySwap[i].length ; j++){
                value = value+1;
                arySwap[i][j]= value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `arySwap[i][columns]` is an `int`, not an array. Just do `i < rows` and `j < columns`.

Comment: Thats right. I've changed to code

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. What's the significance of `arySwap[rows].length`?

Comment: Please change  `for (int i=0 ; i<arySwap[rows].length ; i++){` with  `for (int i=0 ; i<rows ; i++){` as suggested by @shmosel. Same for j

Comment: Yes, changed it. Thanks to you both. Today is not my day ;)

Comment: If you still want to use the array length, then use `i<arySwap.length` and please think about why your first version wouldn't work.